# Numerical data and different algorithms

Tags: classification, clustering, algorithms, weka, association-rules

I was hoping to get some help on a task I have been given. I have a data set with the chemical breakdown of a drink. My job is to find some sort of analysis with the given data. The data has 10 different attributes and a numerical value associated with each attribute and roughly 300 instances of it. I have to use Weka and perform some sort of Clustering, Association, or Classification algorithm. I cannot think of a good analysis that can be done with this data!

At first I thought of using the clustering algorithm but that does not tell me much besides clustering the the data into the number of clusters I assign and telling me the mean composition of each chemical per cluster. Not much of analysis there.

I was hoping someone might be able to guide me in coming up with a good analysis prompt I can do with this data!

Comment: You have to start with a question. What you are actually doing is to find answers to unknown questions. Think about some good questions which you want to answer and then for each one you can think of a question if you are in doubt.